# Take a segment from a list

Tags: python, list

Other than using a loop, is there a method to take a segment from a list.

For example, if I had the list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

and I wanted to take a segment from the 3rd item to the 5th I would end up with...

```
segment = [4,5,6]
```

I know this can be done with a loop but I was wondering if there was a more "pythonic" aproach?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I just wanted to say that __1__ isn't a valid variable name. I'm not sure if it's different with lists...

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy: I think it's a lower-case L, but lower-case L is discouraged as a var name for precisely that reason, it's too easy to confuse with 1.

Comment: @Marius yeah, it's kinda confusing...

Comment: That's why PEP8 recommends against using `l` as a variable name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l[3:6]` is what you are looking for.

This uses list slicing. `3` is the start index. `6` is the end index. We mention `6` as the end index (even though index of 6 is 5) because the slice notation requires the index of the element after the last element we need to be part of the segment.

Demo:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> l[3:6]
[4, 5, 6]
```

This answer explains how slicing on Python lists work - [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)